# Can't connect to windows updates

Tags: windows-xp, updates

I've got a Windows XP machine running sp3 and I'm trying to connect to windows updates, but it's not connecting.  I keep getting the following screen:

[image]

I can connect to the internet just fine, just not to windows updates.  What's keeping me from connecting and what steps can I take to fix this?

Also, I checked and I can connect to norton.com and bitdefender.com, so I'm hesitant to think it's conficker.

Comment: What happens when you try to ping that domain?

Comment: @music2myear sometimes it pings fine, sometimes it times out.  when it was working fine i still got the above message in IE.

Comment: Ok, then I would check the standard malware stuff before proceeding in troubleshooting.

Comment: After checking malware/hosts file, check your router.  I had a similar problem recently with windows update and it turned out the router was flaky.

Comment: I ran Malware Bytes and Bitdefender's online scan and neither came up with anything.

Comment: apparently my malware bytes was out of date.  got it updated and ran it again and it remove some stuff.  ran once more to make sure and it came up clean.  still can't connect.

Comment: Few quick thoughts: 1) Maybe you have some IE add-ons installed (`Tools > Manage Addons`), 2) Try launching the URL in other browser like Firefox and see what happens, 3) The URL you wrote redirects me to http://www.update.microsoft.com/microsoftupdate/v6/default.aspx?ln=en-us - maybe try directly that URL.